# Remove duplicates based on sort

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a customers table with ID's and some datetime columns. But those ID's have duplicates and i just want to Analyse distinct ID values. 
I tried using groupby but this makes the process very slow.
Due to data sensitivity can't share it.
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using ROW_NUMBER() This lets you rank the rows by chosen columns and you can then pick out the first result.

Given you've shared no data or table and column names here's an example based on the Adventureworks database. The technique will be the same, you partition by whatever makes the group of rows you want to deduplicate unique (ProductKey below) and order in a way that makes the version you want to keep first (Children, birthdate and customerkey in my example).

```
USE AdventureWorksDW2017;



WITH CustomersOrdered AS   
(    
SELECT S.ProductKey, C.CustomerKey, C.TotalChildren, C.BirthDate    
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (    
                        PARTITION BY S.ProductKey 
                        ORDER BY C.TotalChildren DESC, C.BirthDate DESC, C.CustomerKey ASC   
                    ) AS CustomerSequence
FROM dbo.FactInternetSales AS S    
INNER JOIN dbo.DimCustomer AS C    
    ON S.CustomerKey = C.CustomerKey    
    )    
SELECT ProductKey, CustomerKey    
FROM CustomersOrdered    
WHERE CustomerSequence = 1    
ORDER BY ProductKey, CustomerKey;
```

Comment: Ah, I misread the keywords, this example would be within SQL but the principal would be similar in Power BI. Add a calculated column to rank the rows then filter on that.

Answer (score 0):

you can also just sort the columns with date column an than click on id column and delete duplicates...

Comment: Table.Buffer(table as table) as table use this command before deleting duplicates...